# Order of the "for" instruction over Array<>

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop

In my code I have this:

```
Array<Block> blocks;
```

At different times, objects are added into that array, and at a regular interval I need to check which of them are too old and need to be removed.

I use the `for` instruction:

```
    Array<Block> to_be_removed = new Array<Block>();
    for (Block b : blocks) {
        if (shouldBeRemoved(b)) {
            to_be_removed.add(b);
        }
    }
    blocks.removeAll(to_be_removed, true);
```

The function `shouldBeRemoved` is constructed in such a way that the blocks that should be removed are always the oldest (have been added before the other blocks).

What I want is to optimize this function: if I assume that the `for` loop will iterate through the objects **in the order that they were added** then once I reach a block that should not be removed I can break the loop and save a lot of time (usually about 5-9 blocks must be removed at each iteration out of a total of 25-35) by not checking the condition for the other blocks.

My question is: what kind of structure should I use to be sure that the `for` loop iterates the objects by their "age" (i.e. the older ones appear first). Is it `Array`, `List`, `ArrayList`, `Set` etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). It implements the [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface, so it provides `add` and `poll` to add elements at the end and remove them front the front.

Comment: If the number of objects is around 25-35 and you are removing atmost 10, I think what you have is good. It seems you are looking for a premature optimisation. Remember the saying - `Premature optimization is the root of all evil`. That being said, if your logic of `shouldBeRemoved` is quite complex, perhaps, you should focus on that. Consider implementing the `Comparator` interface for `Block`. But then again, I may have made it more complicated than it already is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an `ArrayList` and always use `add(E object)` method to add new elements (not using the overloaded method that specify the index of a new element), that will work as you want as, according to [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29), it

> Adds the specified object at the end of this ArrayList.

So when you loop over the list using `for ( : )` loop, it will start with the oldest elements.